# GCP migration password limit prevents me from reading from Heroku PostgreSQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, heroku

I'm trying to migrate data from Heroku's hosted PostgreSQL to GCP's CloudSQL via migration tool.

The credentials that can be generated via Heroku always use "a dynamically generated, 65-byte alphanumeric character string". However, the GCP migration tool allows to use passwords with a length of maximum 32 characters.

I was wondering if there's either a way to:

- change credentials password on Heroku (not possible via PostgreSQL `alter role`)
- make GCP accept longer password for connection profile

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the UI for migration, there is this [article](https://medium.com/@himanshusaraswat/migrating-from-heroku-postgres-to-google-cloud-sql-in-5-minutes-5f92093a1479) with the steps provided on migrating Heroku PostgreSQL to GCP Cloud SQL:

1. Take the dump from Heroku Postgres.

   `pg\_dump`

   `-U USERNAME`

   `--format=plain`

   `--no-owner -h HEROKU\_DB\_HOST`

   `--no-acl SOURCE\_DATABASE\_NAME \| sed -E ‘s/(DROP\|CREATE\|COMMENT ON) EXTENSION/--\\1 EXTENSION/g’ \> YOUR\_OUTPUT\_FILE.sql`
2. Upload/drop the .sql file to cloud storage.
3. Import the file to the database of your choice.

As it seems that making GCP accept longer passwords is not yet possible.